# PHP send mail works in Firefox no but no longer with Internet Explorer

Tags: firefox, windows-explorer, php, mime-types

The following PHP send mail function works in Firefox and used to, but no longer works on at least one version of Internet Explorer (10.0.5).  I am not certain when this happened, but seems related to some form of change in IE or our hosts migration preparations for 4 to 5.2 PHP.  Note that the function works fine in Firefox even under PHP 5.4 environment.

Affected function follow, any help would be greatly appreciated (note style items removed to make code easier to view/debug):

```
<?php
$comments=nl2br($comments);
$date=date("F d,Y h:i:s a");

$body=" <table width='650' align='left' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' style=' background-color:#FFFFFF; margin-bottom:10px;'>
<tr><td colspan='2' style='text-align:left; background-color:#FFFFFF; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px; color:#000000; font-weight:bold; padding:5px;'>Quote Request:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style='font-size:11px; color:#000000; font-weight:normal;'>Submitted &nbsp;".$date."&nbsp;</span><hr></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Name:</td>
<td>".$_REQUEST['name']."</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Company:</td>
<td>".$_REQUEST['company']."</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Title:</td>
<td>".$_REQUEST['title']."</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Phone #:</td>
<td>".$_REQUEST['phone']."</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Email:</td>
<td>".$_REQUEST['email']."</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Product or service type:</td>
<td>".$_REQUEST['product']."</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Description of the product or service:</td>
<td>".$_REQUEST['description']."</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Project type:</td>
<td>".$_REQUEST['product_type']."</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Project overview:</td>
<td>".$_REQUEST['overview']."</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Please summarize project's objectives:</td>
<td>".$_REQUEST['summarize']."</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td># of users to test (if applicable):</td>
<td>".$_REQUEST['user_test']."</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Supported computing platforms (if applicable):</td>
<td>".$_REQUEST['supported_computing']."</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Project depth required:</td>
<td>".$_REQUEST['depth']."</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Project's status:</td>
<td>".$_REQUEST['project_status']."</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>When would you like to begin?</td>
<td>".$_REQUEST['like_begin']."</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>When will you need the results?</td>
<td>".$_REQUEST['result']."</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>How should we contact you?</td>
<td>".$_REQUEST['Contact']."</td>
</tr>
</table>";

if($_POST['email']!="")
{

    $body =$body;
    $subject="Quote Request";
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: " .$_REQUEST['email']. "\r\n";
    $to="details@ourURL.com";
   // $to="";
    mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);
```

Comment: Probably a better fit for stackoverflow

Comment: You removed stuff to make the code easier to view/debug?  Try removing more; that’s still too much to read, and I can’t believe that it’s all relevant.  Also, your post seems to be truncated in mid-function: there’s (at least) one more `{` than `}`.  Also, use `&amp;`, `&lt;`, and `&gt;` to encode `&`, `<`, and `>`.